# Consider a man who travelled exactly 2 km in two hours. Is there a one-hour interval when he traveled exactly 1 km?

Tags: calculus, applications

Consider a man who travelled exactly 2 km in two hours.

Is there a one-hour interval when he traveled exactly 1 km?

Can we make a mathematical argument?

I have written my attempt in an answer below. Does anyone else have a better approach?
Are my assumptions not necessary, or we can produce counter examples without them? Can we make-do with some intermediate assumptions?

(This is not the same as the Universal Chord question because there's no $f$ with $f(0)=f(1)$ and there's no continuity assumption. Answers to the cyclist question are not satisfactory.)

Comment: No continuity assumption? Can we suppose he was simply teleported to the destination at some point in time?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I meant that about velocity

Comment: @whoisit, the distance function $d$ _does_ have to be continuous. (What I think you mean is that it is not necessarily differentiable.) So the Universal Chord Theorem applies here to the function $f(t)=d(t)-t$.

Comment: After applying a quantum distribution on a closed 2km box with a base energy level that has its smallest factor being 3; I find no 1km distance exists; therefore I have found a counterexample.

Comment: Interestingly, you need that the total distance is an integer for this to be true. For example, cover 1.5km in 1.5 hours by covering 0.5km segments steadily in 20 minutes, then 50 minutes, then 20 minutes. Every 1km segment is traversed in exactly 70 minutes, although the average pace is 1km/hr. (Note every 1km segment contains the middle 0.5km plus a total of 0.5km from the first and last portions.) Discussed here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00871

Comment: While the upvoted answer is certainly correct, the short answer already appears in the comments: this is *exactly* the Universal Chord Theorem, applied to $f(t)=d(2t)-2t$.  You have $f(0)=f(1)=1$ and, yes, $f$ is continuous.  You can conclude that there are time intervals of length exactly $1$ hour, $40$ minutes, $30$ minutes, $24$ minutes, $20$ minutes, etc., over which the runner’s average velocity is $1$ km/hr.

Comment: Consider a man who traveled exactly *1 km an hour for two hours*. Is there a one-hour interval when he traveled exactly 1 km? Um, yeah: any interval that's an hour long. Don't need math unless it wasn't a constant velocity, and if it wasn't and we don't have what it was, then we can't say much.

Comment: @Mazura: I believe the question is whether, for all travels that meet the criteria described in the question, there *must* be such an interval; your comment merely points out that there is *some* travel that has such an interval (and, as the answers show, we can actually say much even if the velocity was not constant).

Comment: @usul: Thanks for the link and interesting article. "Interestingly, you need that the total distance is an integer for this to be true." something's missing in your description, though. 2km is ~1.24 miles, so is it "an integer"? The description in the article is "there must be a subset covered in the average speed if and only
if the length of the entire race is an integer multiple of the length of the
subinterval of interest".

Comment: @EricDuminil right, "integer" should be "integer multiple of the subinterval length". If the sub-interval is one kilometer as in this question, then the total length should be an integer number of kilometers.

Answer (score 63):

Let $d(t)$ be the distance travelled at time $t$ (in hours). We have $d(0) = 0$ and $d(2) = 2$. It is safe to assume that $d$ is continuous.
We want to find a $t\in[0;1]$ with
$$d(t+1) - d(t) = 1.$$
Define an auxiliary function
$$f(t) = d(t+1) - d(t) - 1.$$
Thus, our condition becomes $f(t) = 0$.

We have that
$$\begin{align*}
f(0) &= d(1) - d(0) - 1 = d(1) - 1 \\
f(1) &= d(2) - d(1) - 1 = 1 - d(1) = -f(0)
\end{align*}$$ Thus:

If $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, then we are done.

If $f(0) \neq 0$, we have that $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ have different signs. By the intermediate value theorem, there is a $t\in (0;1)$ with $f(t) = 0$, as desired.

Answer (score 3):

The velocity $v(t)$ is either continuous or has discontinuities at a finite number of points.
Thus, let's assume $v(t)$ is an integrable function and hence its integration is continuous.
For $t \in [0, 1]$, we define the distance traveled in the next hour: $$ d(t) = \displaystyle\int_{t}^{t+1hr} v(t) dt  $$

Easier way to define $d$ without any velocity assumption: Let $p(t)$ be the position of the man - and define $d(t)=p(t+1)-p(t)$. As teleportation is not allowed, $p$ is continuous, thus so is $d$.

We want to find whether there is always a $t$ where $d(t)$ takes the value 1 km.
We know that $d(0)+d(1)=2$.

WLOG assume $m = d(0) \leq d(1) = n $.
Then, either $m=n=1$ in which case we're done, or we have
$m<1<n$, in which case we can use continuity of $d(t)$ to invoke Intermediate Value Theorem to claim that there was some $t$ in between where the value was $1$.

Comment: You don't need any assumptions about the velocity, as Tobius' answer shows.

Comment: I find this answer much more intuitive than Tobius'. However, the bit about integrals is superfluous. You can define $d(t)$ as "distance traveled between $t$ and $t+1$" and everything in your answer remains correct, and this correctly proves the existence of $t$ such that $d(t) = 1$. You don't need to know that $d(t) = \int_{t}^{t+1}v(t) dt$ and so you don't need any assumptions about integrability or continuity of the velocity (or even *existence* of a velocity function at all). All you need to know is that $d(t)$ is continuous, which is equivalent to "the traveler did not teleport".

Comment: "or has discontinuities at a finite number of points" - and the question has no meaningful answer? - At 2000mph that takes 4 seconds. So between 0:0:02 and 1:0:02 they went one mile. That's *assuming* they didn't just stand there between 0 seconds and 1:59:56 hours.

Answer (score -1):

With the continuity assumption, define a function on the interval $t \in [1,2]$ by $d_1 (t) \equiv d(t) - d(t-1)$, the distance covered within the last hour, where $d(t)$ is the position at time $t$. Then $d_1 (1) = d(1) - d(0) = d(1)$, and $d_1 (2) = d(2) - d(1) = 2 - d(1)$. The mean of the two boundary values $d(1)$ and $2 - d(1)$ of the function $d_1 (t)$ is $1$, therefore $1 \in [d_1 (1), d_1 (2) ] $ no matter what $d(1)$ is, and by the intermediate value theorem there exists a $t_0 \in [1,2]$ such that $d_1(t_0 ) = 1$.